# Show git changes at left side of the editor in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control

I don't know why, but my Android Studio now is showing the git changes on the right side of the text editor only and I cannot interact with it using the mouse for review/revert/diff.

How can I set up to show the version control system changes at the left side of the editor, as before?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Preference on android studio :
[image]